# JS. Как при нажатии на radiobutton показать(visible) кнопку(button), когда он спрятан в hidden? Исправьте пожалуйста код

Tags: javascript, button, for, hidden

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Опрос 8"A"</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="a">a<br>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="b">b<br>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="c">c<br>

    <div id="descr" style="visibility: hidden">
        <button id="one">Отправить</button>
    </div>

    <script>


            document.getElementById("one").onclick = checkRadio;

        function checkRadio() {
            var m = document.getElementsByName('prim');
            for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
                if (m[i].checked) {
                    document.getElementById("descr").style.visibility = "visible";  
                    alert(m[i].value);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
        
        var rad = document.getElementsByName('prim');
        
        rad.forEach(e => {
           e.onchange = function(){
               document.getElementById("descr").style.visibility = "visible";
               alert(e.value);
               return;
           };
        });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Опрос 8"A"</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="a">a<br>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="b">b<br>
    <input type="radio" name="prim" value="c">c<br>

    <div id="descr" style="visibility: hidden">
        <button id="one">Отправить</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var button = document.getElementById("one"),
  value;
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName != 'INPUT') return;
    if (target.checked) {
      button.parentNode.style.visibility = "visible";
      value = target.value;
    }
  }

);
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(value);
  }

)
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Опрос 8"A"</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="radio" name="prim" value="a">a<br>
  <input type="radio" name="prim" value="b">b<br>
  <input type="radio" name="prim" value="c">c<br>

  <div id="descr" style="visibility: hidden">
    <button id="one">Отправить</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!